# How to avoid redeclaring ticks on every file in PHP 7

Tags: php, profiling

**Overview**

In PHP 5.6 it seems that adding `declare(ticks=1)` and then using `register_tick_function()` would follow any includes and provide profiling information accordingly.

In PHP 7+ however it now seems I have to add `declare(ticks=1)` in every file. I use this for profiling every method call on a page load and don't now want to add this to each PHP file in my system (some I can't if they are in libraries).

I can't find anything in the docs about changes that were made to this.

**Replication Steps**

Create the below 2 files:

**index.php**

```
<?php

declare(ticks=1);
$count = 0;

register_tick_function('ticker');
function ticker() {
  global $count;
  $count++;
}

$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

include dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc.php';

echo $count;
```

**inc.php**

```
<?php

#declare(ticks=1);

$baz = "baz";
$qux = "qux";
```

**Results**

Running `php index.php` in the terminal gives me:

- PHP 5.6 - 7
- PHP 7.0 - 5

With `declare(ticks=1)` uncommented in `inc.php` the results are:

- PHP 5.6 - 8
- PHP 7.0 - 8

**Question**

Is there any way to way to force it to follow includes and in a sense make it global in PHP 7+?

Comment: Could there be some optimization in PHP7 that it detects that it doesn't need to run any code in `inc.php`. Can you change `inc.php` to write something to a file. And then check the numbers again.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. If I do a full check using `debug_backtrace()` it doesn't even pick up the files inside `inc.php`

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. `debug_backtrace()` doesn't have a guaranteed side effect. `file_put_contents` does have a guaranteed side-effect so the compiler can't optimize it away.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow - can you explain further? If I replace the `$count` with a `var_dump(debug_backtrace())`, the file key never references `inc.php` - it does in PHP 5.6 however

Comment: in `inc.php` change `$baz = "baz";` to `file_put_contents("txt.txt", "baz");` etc.

Comment: Still the same counts...

Comment: And it does write to the file in all cases?

Comment: Yeah, the file has been written correctly...

Comment: What if you do a `require` instead of `include`? What if the included file doesn't contain any live code but only a function. Does it count the ticks when you call that function?

Comment: Changing to `require` makes no difference. Clearing the `inc.php` file makes both tick counts the same. I would expect that though because if there is nothing in the file there is nothing for either PHP version to run and therefore fire a tick.

Comment: This has had been stumped all last night and all today and can't for the life of me work out what has changed and the docs don't seem to reference it anywhere. I've run all sorts of tests, all of which work on PHP 5.6 and not on PHP 7

Comment: I see on http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php _"A script's encoding can be specified per-script using the encoding directive."_ maybe `declare` now works on a per-file basis? Or maybe they introduced a bug.

Comment: This is the problem, it could potentially be either but I can't find any explicit information online about either case.

Comment: Have at it: https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: I'll give it a go and report back if I get anything concrete in response. Thanks for your help trying to debug this though, some helpful suggestions.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71448

Comment: Due to an implementation bug, the declare(ticks=1) directive leaked into different compilation units prior to PHP 7.0. This is not how declare() directives, which are per-file or per-scope, are supposed to work.

Comment: So, it begs a different question then... Is there another way to profile every function call on a page load or to force declare(ticks=1) to run on each file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PHP bug filed at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71448

> Due to an implementation bug, the declare(ticks=1) directive leaked into different compilation units prior to PHP 7.0. This is not how declare() directives, which are per-file or per-scope, are supposed to work.

So in fact it was a bug that it ever did work as it did in PHP 5.6 and the correct implementation has been added in PHP 7.0. Unfortunately this means it will never work but at least there is an explanation.

There is an answer on the below question that shows how to achieve this in PHP 7+

[Natively profile multiple scripts in PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473694/natively-profile-multiple-scripts-in-php7)