# Natively profile multiple scripts in PHP7

Tags: php, profiling, php-7

Since the release of PHP 7 it is now not possible to profile an entire selection of scripts using `declare(ticks=1)` in your base file and then using `register_tick_function()` to monitor each tick as it no longer follows include paths. According to the PHP bug filed at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71448 this will never be available again in PHP 7.

> Due to an implementation bug, the declare(ticks=1) directive leaked into different compilation units prior to PHP 7.0. This is not how declare() directives, which are per-file or per-scope, are supposed to work.

Are there any alternatives to this approach using native PHP (not C or pear extensions etc.) that are available to me in PHP 7 that will allow me to profile each function or file called in a page load, getting details of the actual file path at least.

My original question that led to finding the bug can be found at [How to avoid redeclaring ticks on every file in PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440613/how-to-avoid-redeclaring-ticks-on-every-file-in-php-7), this question is now about alternative methods.

Comment: Without adding inspections directly to the PHP interpreter (i.e. through an extension), this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common way to do this without `declare(ticks=1)` is to use a profiler. A profiler will take notice of *any* method/function called, file loaded etc. and even take timing information so you not only can say which function was called when and by what code and which files were opened but also which part of the program took how long.

A well known profiler in PHP comes with the famous **Xdebug extension**. It also ships with a debugger:

- https://xdebug.org/

One benefit is that you don't need to change the code to do the profiling, it is just the PHP configuration you need to adopt so you can switch it on and off as you need it (e.g. debug / profiling session).

### PHP Userland (tick function)

As a work-around not having `declare(ticks=1);` at the beginning of each file (after [#71448](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71448)), it is possible to add this on-the-fly via a stream-wrapper on the *file* protocol (for files in the local file-system which is common) that injects it.

This is technically feasible by creating a stream-wrapper that is registered on the file protocol to proxy standard file i/o operations. In this [PoC (Gist on Github)](https://gist.github.com/hakre/45df61688fb3f6f10101bd2cdb24d0e6) the bare-minimum implementation is shown to demonstrate that it works for includes. When `test.php` is executed and despite that `other.php` has not `declare(ticks=1);` in it on disk, the registered tick function is called on the include as the print of the backtraces show:

```
...
tick_handler() called
#0  tick_handler(1) called at [/home/hakre/stream-wrapper-default-files/test.php:18]
#1  tick_handler() called at [/home/hakre/stream-wrapper-default-files/other.php:2]
#2  include(/home/hakre/stream-wrapper-default-files/other.php) called at [/home/hakre/stream-wrapper-default-files/test.php:24]
...
```

The output is generated from the registered tick function (here: test.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * Inject declare ticks on include
 */
declare(ticks=1);

require __DIR__ . '/streamwrapper.php';

FileStreamWrapper::init();

// using a function as the callback
register_tick_function('tick_handler', true);


// Function which is called on each tick-event
function tick_handler()
{
    echo "tick_handler() called\n";
    debug_print_backtrace();
}

register_tick_function('tick_handler');

include "other.php";
include "another.php"; # file does not exists
```

The [stream wrapper in the gist example](https://gist.github.com/hakre/45df61688fb3f6f10101bd2cdb24d0e6#file-streamwrapper-php) has only implemented as little as needed to work for the two include statements, as PHP scripts normally do more file i/o it needs to be extended as needed. When it goes about seeking etc., the dynamic insertion needs to be taken into account etc. but there is state per file operation (handle) as there is one instance per each one so this should be well encapsulated. The global state is used for registering/unregistering the stream wrapper for each operation to proxy into the real file-system functions as otherwise it creates endless recursion (wrapper uses the wrapper uses the wrapper ...). The PoC so far shows how it works on principle.

This can be (mis-)used for other things as well, but this PoC is for your specific declare ticks and include use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however thats why I said natively in PHP 7. I use xdebug already but I want a way to do this myself for creating a profiling solution that doesnt require installing anything extra.

Comment: To be fair, xdebug is pretty prominent and widely available. I can understand you're looking for portability, so it seemed the first option to me. For userland profiling there is quite some existing Q&A material on the site giving suggestions, but as you also might have realized there is none with the declare ticks. You could intercept includes with a stream wrapper (theoretical) und insert the declares in there. There is also a function you can call to obtain the list of files included so far: http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-included-files.php

Comment: Unfortunately it's not widely available enough for my needs. I've also played with the included files function, however I can't really use it for profiling how long each included file ran for etc. (as far as I can see). I'm interested in your idea of using stream wrappers though - these are not something I've used before. Are you able to elaborate on this idea or provide any good reading material to point me towards your thinking?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone: I can create a PoC which injects a declare into each file on inclusion transparently. Please mind that this will be only a PoC. I'll add it exemplary, need to check if the idea works.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone: Edited and posted the code as gist / example inlined in the answer.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone: For your userland needs, please see http://patchwork2.org/ it also has such a stream-wrapper already in there. I think this is a good project to suggest modifying declare statements if it does not yet support that feature. I just stumbled upon it while looking more into this, I couldn't imagine that such a stream wrapper hasn't been created already.

Comment: This works very well. I'm just having some issues with classes that are auto-loaded via composer but if I can overcome that hurdle this should do exactly as I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's so sad that this stream wrapper implementation is incomplete and not really working! The Patchwork library doesn't offer the feature OOTB either, and implementing stream wrappers correctly is NIGHTMARISHLY DIFFICULT.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski: There are working implementation available in other venues on Github and as well elsewhere. See related projects like "Patchwork PHP" and similar. So far for a quick comment.